# BizTalk App Insights UI Fails as Not Able to Select from Drop-Down Lists

Tags: biztalk, azure-application-insights, biztalk-2016

I have BizTalk 2016 FP3 CU5 installed. I want to configure to send telemetry to an Azure Application Insights instance.

From the BizTalk admin consolve, I right-click the group icon and select Settings.

In the "Analytics" section I select "Applicaton Insights" and login to my Azure Account.

[image]

I am then not able to make any selections from the drop-down lists for Subscription, Resource Group etc.

I am sure that the account I signed in with has a valid subscription which contains a resource group that contains an Application Insights instance

Comment: What set of permissions you have in Azure  for that particular resource group or application insights instance ?  Are you able to reach to Azure portal and view the resources from the same box where your BizTalk instance is running ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are my input:

- Login to `http://portal.azure.com` with the same credential and see if you have the right set of permission in the subscription/Resource group and then application insight(AI) instance.
- If yes, Please copy the instrumentation key of your AI instance. You can find it here:

[image]

which later on you can provide it below in Biztalk conifguration.

[image]

It will unblock you. Hope it helps.

Comment: I think you must be using an older version of BizTalk? I'm using 2016 FP3, this has a UI that presents a button "..." adjacent to the "Connection parameters" text box.